# Generate hash of image file selected for upload (before the upload)?

Tags: angular

I've got a method by which a user can click a button on my form and select a file to preview (in this case a .png) and upload (ultimately to Firebase storage bucket).  Before it uploads, I would like to calculate an MD5 hash on the file.  Problem is I'm not sure how to get hold of the files contents for hashing.

Here the method I use one the user has selected a file using an  tag in my angular component:

```
async upload(evt: Event) {
    let target: HTMLInputElement = evt.target as HTMLInputElement;
    this.fileObject = target.files[0];
    this.firestorePath =BK.normalizeFileName(this.prepublishSevice.current.publisherName);
    let url = URL.createObjectURL(this.fileObject);
    this.mediaFileName = this.fileObject.name
    this.mediaFileType = this.fileObject.type;
    this.previewImage = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);

  }
```

That works fine to use as source for an image tag in template.

What I would like to do is read and produce an MD5 of the image but I am a bit lost there.

Looking at related questions, I tried to extend the above function with:

```
let reader = new FileReader();
let image : any
const loaded = (value)=>{
  imag = value.target.result;   
}
reader.onload = loaded;
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.fileObject);
this.hashval = Md5.hashStr(image, true);
```

But image remained undefined.  Using reader.readAsBinary didn't work either, I got an error complaingin that (this.fileObject) isn't a blob.

So any help in what I am supposed to be reading and how, and then how I can produce an Md5 hash of it (which hopefully is the same as the Md5 google cloud will produce when I upload it.